# Dialogflow prebuilt agent's Make Appointment intent seems to be buggy on initial deployment

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

First, when you follow the tutorial [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook) and deploy the recommended prebuilt agent, and you view the Inline Editor under fulfillment, the editor displays a warning/error on line 82:

> expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

code snippet throwing up the error:

```
 err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
```

Having set up the Google Calender API and updated the parameter in index.js file, the prebuilt agent returns this error below when "Make Appointment intent" is run. the `appointmentDateString` constant can not read and parse the time parameter correctly.

> Sorry, we're booked on Invalid Date at Invalid Date. Is there anything else I can do for you?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the date format is not correct beacause there are two timeZoneOffset in the string to parse to Date.

In order to solve this issue, erase one of the timeoffset.

```
function convertParametersDate(date, time){
//ORIGINAL
  //return new Date(Date.parse(date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] **+ timeZoneOffset**));

//SOLVED
  return new Date(Date.parse(date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0]));
}
```